# Display a sprite with no image - PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection, tile

I am working on a game project meant for learning and I was thinking if I create a sprite without a set image. I need this because I have an ideea to keep the value of the rect tiles that need collision in a sprite group. Is it possible?

Comment: Can't you just not draw it?

Comment: Yes, but I work with an universal group of sprites. Is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of sprites excluding the invisible sprite(s):

```
all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
```

Then for collision just make a barrier list and put your invisible sprites that need collision in it.